# Highchart - When rotate x-axis label fonts are big and blur

Tags: highcharts

```
xAxis : {
  categories : dept,
    labels : {
       style : {
            fontSize : '12px',
            fontFamily : 'Verdana',
            align : 'right'
       }
    }
}
```

Picture when few data (not rotate label)

[image: Picture when few data (not rotate label)]

Picture when many data (rotate label)

[image: Picture when many data (rotate label)]

How can I fix it? I use IE 11.
Is it about the compatibility of the browser?

Comment: Can you recreate this on jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/8t7t9xsv/ The example I pasted do not has blurred fonts in the latest chrome/ie11

Comment: Thank you morganfree. I have tried on jsfiddle.net/8t7t9xsv and it works fine,but in my project it doesn't work.